# Margin TableRow

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

I've looked through all the people that have asked the same thing and no one has ever answered correctly the question. For some reason I can't seem to find how to do this.
I need to add a margin between each of my dynamically made TableRows.
This is what I have now.
[image: Android]

As you can see, the rows are way together, making the GUI not usable for a user.
The TableLayout is inside a ScrollView.
This is the code I use to create dynamically the TextView and  the button. I have tried using margins but no luck so far

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);

    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    /* Margin. */
    int leftMargin = 0;
    int topMargin = 200;
    int rightMargin = 0;
    int bottomMargin = 0;

    /* Set margins and create new textview. */
    tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin,
            bottomMargin);
    tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
    TextView encuestasTextView = new TextView(this);
    encuestasTextView.setText("Esto es una prueba");
    encuestasTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tr.addView(encuestasTextView);

    Button a = new Button(this);
    a.setText("Abrir encuesta");
    a.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(width / 3,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tr.addView(a);

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Encuestas" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1">


</TableLayout>


 </ScrollView>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="SyncServer"
    android:text="Sync" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
 tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

is wiping out the layout params you set earlier.  Just use `tl.addView(tr);`

Comment: Amazing! Never though of the view changing everything! Now works